# Need enlightment about NPath complexity

Tags: eclipse, pmd, code-complexity

I added PMD to my Eclipse workspace and I'm working on cleaning the code.

My most complex method says it has a NPath complexity of 804, ok no problem, it probably need refactoring.

But then I've something that look rather simple that has a NPath complexity of 3125, that seems just wrong :

```
public void toUpperParams() {
    valueParam1 = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(valueParam1) ? valueParam1.toUpperCase() : null;
    valueParam2 = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(valueParam2) ? valueParam2.toUpperCase() : null;
    valueParam3 = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(valueParam3) ? valueParam3.toUpperCase() : null;
    valueParam4 = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(valueParam4) ? valueParam4.toUpperCase() : null;
    valueParam5 = StringUtils.isNotEmpty(valueParam5) ? valueParam5.toUpperCase() : null;
}
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ternary increases the NPath factor.
Below two explanations I could find:

[Question on Guthub](https://github.com/pdepend/pdepend/issues/158)

[Question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079923/pmd-npath-complexity-very-high-with-ternary-operator)

Comment: Thank you. Still sound weird, if anyone know why this decision was taken I'm eager to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you miss anything. According to my calculation, NPath should be 10 based on the definition, which was given in the following article: [NPath complexity](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=42379)

Comment: I tried it out with SourceMeter, and it gave 11 for NPath complexity for this method.